# Trying to use a "Calculated Value" as the "Default value" in a choice column

Tags: choice-field, default-value

I am creating a drop-down choice column. For the default, I need to use a value that is based off of a value from another table. Here's the challenge.

In table A, I have a list of organizations. I have a column called "Needs Stuff", it's a one line text field.

In table A, I also created a calculated column called "nsCalc", using the formula: =IF([Needs Stuff]="","N/A","Pending"). Works perfectly.

In table B, I created a lookup from table A and added the columns "A:Needs Stuff" and "A:nsCalc". They show up correctly when viewing table B.

My challange is a drop-down choice column in table B, using a Calculated Value as the Default value using "A:nsCalc":

- Value from A:nsCalc (default)
- N/A
- Pending
- Approved

So far I am failing. There must be a way, but I am not finding it. Any ideas?

Using SharePoint on O365.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it like this because Lookups are internally based on reference-ids and not the values.

As Formulas can not expand these complex types (same applies to:  Multiple Select, [Me] and Person Columns) you can not use them in Calculated Columns

Your workaround is to use Workflows to read the Complex type value and write it to a basic Text column, and then do your magic

Comment: Great idea! I hadn't thought of that. That might work as I have a workflow in place coying date from one table to the others. I can add this in.

Thank you!

Comment: Ran into another snag. Because the field in table A is a calculated field and the field in table B is text, the workflow will not copy the value over as the fields are different types.